# How to reinitialize console when clicking the close button?

Tags: python, pyqt, spyder

I am building a simple GUI for selecting files using PYQT, and I am working with the Spyder IDE. When I try to close the GUI with the red "X" button and run the file again, a warning message pops up that says:

```
No Python shell is currently selected to run **readFile.py**
Please select or open a new Python interpreter and try again
```

How can I make the red X button reinitialize the interpreter and console without having to manually do it every time? Here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Example(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lbl = QtGui.QLabel('Please Choose Excel File',self)

        openButton = QtGui.QPushButton('Choose File')
        openButton.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)

        vbox.addWidget(lbl)        
        vbox.addWidget(openButton)
        self.setLayout(vbox)
        self.setGeometry(300,300,350,300)
        self.setWindowTitle('file Dialog')
        self.show()

    def showDialog(self):

        fname = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home')
        print(fname)


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) What is your Spyder version? I'm not seeing your error in `2.3rc`. Besides, does the console dies after you close the window?

Comment: It's version 2.3.0beta2, it came as part of WinPython. What happens is that after I close the window (hit the red x), I need to close the python console and open another one, otherwise it won't run again.

Comment: I'll test it on Windows to see if I can reproduce it. But you can also install a more recent version by downloading it from [our website](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads) and see if that solves the problem.